# R write.table with different delimiters

Tags: r, write.table

I would like to save a file with 11 columns. All columns but two have to be separated by a tab and the remaining one by white space (please do not ask me, what sort of programmer came up with this idea, it was not my idea!).

```
m <- data.frame("DIN156", 6, 1, 255, "DINs", "_00:01:00.000000", "_00:00:00.001", "gidx", 1, "cidx", 1)
```

The 4th and 5th column have to be separated by white space, the rest by tabs.

Any idea how to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Something along the line (untested) `apply(m,1,function(x) { sprintf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s %s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s",x) }` should give you a list of lines corresponding to you use case. (I can think of a better method to build the format... but unsure it match what you wish at all)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m <- data.frame("DIN156", 6, 1, 255, "DINs", "_00:01:00.000000", "_00:00:00.001", "gidx", 1, "cidx", 1)
m[, 4] <- paste(m[, 4], m[, 5])
colnames(m)[4] <- paste(colnames(m)[4:5], collapse = " ")
m[, 5] <- NULL
write.table(m, file = "myfile.txt", sep = "\t")
```